# Salesforce - query returns only 500 rows when more exist

Tags: php, web-services, soap, salesforce

First of all, I'm not the one developing this but I'm the one with the SO account. My SF knowledge is almost non-existent.

Basically, the problem is that a query is returning only 500 rows from our PHP script. However when we substitute that query (directly within the PHP) with another, that query returns over 1500 rows. There are definitely over 500 rows that ought to be returned by the first query - I've checked using the data explorer.

Here's the first query:

```
SELECT Id,WEBSITE_ExternalId__c,Name,
.............
from Account
```

And here is the second:

```
SELECT Id,WEBSITE_ExternalId__c,D_STANDARD_Age__c,
..............
from Feedback__c 
ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
```

Any clues? I appreciate this might not be enough information but I don't know much about Salesforce. If there's anything else you'd need to answer this, ask and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Your queries reference two different tables. Are they supposed to have the same number of rows?

Comment: You have terrible naming convention, `CAMEL_Case_ARE_NOT_good` in database

Comment: @ajreal: The client does, actually. These weren't chosen by us. Thanks for reformatting the queries in the answer by the way, I should have done that.

Comment: @Icarus: no, the second query returns ~1555 rows, whereas the first should return ~850. The issue is that the first is being limited to 500 rows, whereas the second is free to return as many rows as it likes. This is when directly swapped within the PHP, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Please post the PHP that that shows you how many rows are being returned. Perhaps do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` to see if it matches up.

Comment: @Mike: This is a Salesforce query. I'm under the impression that COUNT(*) won't work but correct me if wrong. As I've said though, it works fine when the query is replaced so the issue must be with Salesforce/the query.

Comment: To be honest, I've never even heard of Salesforce. I'm just giving generic PHP/SQL answers. I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah. The reason is that it's not MySQL/SQL - it's an object database or something and has less features in terms of syntax. Don't ask me why people would want it... =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large results, the results are batched by the query call, you'll get so many rows, along with a token you can use to fetch the next batch and so on. there's an done flag in the query result, that indicates if this is the last batch in the results or not. if done is false you need to call queryMore passing in the queryLocator (also returned in the queryResult structure). See the docs/examples on [query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm)/[queryMore](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the latest WSDL from Setup > Develop > API, and make sure WSDL cacheing is disabled in your PHP settings: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=786331&language=en.

Also as mentioned in the guide, 500 results is the default for query objects.  In addition to using queryMore() for larger calls, see here for documentation on setting the batch size: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm.