# ForceTk Salesforce Limits?

Tags: salesforce

I am using the ForcetK to query a group of records. The Response says that it has 3000 records but it is only returning 2000 in the Array. Any Ideas?

code:

```
var query = "Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name FROm childObject) FROM object";
client.query(query, response);

 function returnResponse(response) {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Salesforce - query returns only 500 rows when more exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271294/salesforce-query-returns-only-500-rows-when-more-exist)

Comment: The array is not returning the unique records.